# How can I read the custom meta data of my file in dbfs in databricks?

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks

**My metadata var 'last-modified'**

[image]

**my metadata var:**

[image]

I want to read my custom-created meta data in Databricks in Pyspark.

I was able to read the general metadata, but I want to read my custom metadata "last-modified"

```py
df = spark.read \
  .format("csv") \
  .load("filepath") \
  .select("*", "_metadata")

display(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/ingestion/file-metadata-column) there are only **file_path, file_name, file_size, file_modification_time, file_block_start, file_block_length** Supported metadata.

[image]

***you cannot fetch custom metadata with _metadata option in pyspark.***

**Possible Workaround:**

One of the workarounds I can think is make use of the REST API to [Get Blob Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-blob-properties?tabs=azure-ad).

The Get blob properties API returns all user-defined metadata, standard HTTP properties, and system properties for the blob.

Comment: Do I need a key for it?